# Jenkins Auto merge git branch, develop to qa

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to automate the merge process for a repository hosted in git and built by jenkins.

I have two branches, **qa** and **develop**. When I am ready to deploy to QA environment, off of **qa** branch, I would like to automatically merge all the changes from **develop** branch onto **qa** branch via jenkins.

I understand that jenkins provides below listed options while specifying a git repo

> **Checkout/merge to local branch (optional)**
>
> **Merge options    Merge before build**

Also, as a post build action via Git Publisher, I can push commits to remote.

> **Push Only If Build Succeeds**
>
> **Merge Results**

However, I am not able to understand how do I specify that **develop** is the branch from which I am trying to merge from.

If I set the below listed options,I am assuming it will merge "qa" to "develop" and not vice-versa (Which is what I want)

> > **Branches to build** = **qa**
> >
> > **Merge to local branch** = **develop**

If I switch back the options it will merge to "qa", every time I build develop and I do not want that as well. I only want a controlled "qa" build that is triggered manually. However, I should merge all the changes from develop before doing the "qa" build. Any suggestions?

> > **Branches to build** = **develop**
> >
> > **Merge to local branch** = **qa**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ignore the "Merge to local branch" option.

Instead you should configure the refspec so Jenkins will fetch at least both "develop" and "qa" branches. (Or if they are not on the same server, configure two repositories.

Set "develop" as the "Branches to build". Then set "Merge before build". Add "qa" to "Branch to merge to".

I did not quite get what you mean when you say you "want a controlled qa build that is triggered manually". Do you mean you do not want to know as soon as possible when your development branch stops working with your qa branch? If you really want that, you can remove any build triggers for the job. That way you can manually control when to build and when you want to get feedback.

P.S. These days many people think it is essential to get feedback as early as possible, so most people would probably want to build this job every time there is a new commit to "develop" branch.

Comment: Thanks @sti .I have a separate job that triggers build on every commit done on 'develop' branch. This one is more for a release to QA, say at the end of a sprint. I would like to merge all the commits from 'develop' to 'qa' automatically via jenkins. This will usually happen once in 2 weeks but it should be flexible enough to be triggered only when required.